# Sort citations as they appear in the bibliography (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, sorting

According to the `biblatex` manual, the option `sortcites = true` makes sure that "citations are sorted according to the global sorting order of the bibliography" (§3.1.2.1). This is, however, not what I get (using the latest version of `biblatex`). As can be seen below, the order in the text citations is the opposite of the bibliography. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon1972a,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Who did what in the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1972"}
@book{lennon1972b,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "This is why I was the best musician in the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1972"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cites{lennon1972a}{lennon1972b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine with `\cite{lennon1972a,lennon1972b}`. BTW: `authoryear-comp` sets `sortcites=true` automatically.

Comment: The documentation is not particularly clear whether sorting is supposed to work with `\cites{foo}{bar}`; but I think `\cite{foo,bar}` and `\cites{foo}{bar}` are handled significantly differently by `biblatex` (the documentation states that the latter is built on top of the former). That said, `\cite{lennon1972a,lennon1972b}` does work here as well.

Comment: @karlkoeller Using ``\cite`` won't allow things like multiple page references. For that reason, I always use ``\cites``, ``\parencites`` etc. for multiple citations.

Comment: It is the same with `\autocite` and `\autocites`. I always use `\autocites` for similar reasons and `sortcites` only works with `\autocite`. If this is intended, I think the documentation is buggy because the description on page 45 clearly says 'if multiple entry keys are passed to a citation command' which certainly implies *any* citation command. I thought I'd found somewhere in the manual where it did specify this behaviour but now I can't find it.