# How to sort citations by name with biblatex 'sortcites' option

Tags: biblatex, sorting

In my MWE below, I sort my bibliography with the `nyt` option (`name-year-title`), cf. the [biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) under `3.1.2.1 General`. Then I also include `sortcites = true`, which according to the manual will "sort citations if multiple entry keys are passed to a citation command. If this option is enabled, citations are sorted according to the global sorting order of the bibliography."

Since the "global sorting order of the bibliography" in my case is `name-year-title`, I'd expect my citations to be sorted first by `name`, then by `year`, and finally by `title`. But as the MWE below demonstrates, my citations are simply printed in the order given in the cite command. I was expecting "Lennon" to appear before "McCartney" since `l` preceeds `m`, but this does not happen. I am either not understanding what `sortcites` is supposed to do, or I am setting the options incorrectly. What do I need to do to automatically sort my citations by name?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, sorting = nyt, sortcites = true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mccartney1965,
    author = "Paul McCartney",
    title = "Yesterday",
    year = "1965"}
@book{lennon1967,
    author = "John Lennon",
    title = "Lucy in the sky with diamonds",
    year = "1967"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites{mccartney1965}{lennon1967}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\cites` multicite commands are not designed to sort their arguments, but Audrey has found a way to make them do it anyway [Sorting citations using \cites command in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65809/35864). BTW: [Didn't you ask this before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157377/35864)

Comment: I have tried, and I obtained "Lennon" before McCartney. Did you run biber after changing the option? it's biber which make the sorting. So must run.

Comment: @moewe But aren't multicite commands the only command where "multiple entry keys are passed to a citation command"? Does this mean that ``sortcites`` is simply an vacant command?

Comment: @moewe that is true if you don't use sorting like nty.

Comment: `sortcites` is not vacant, you can use `\cite{mccartney1965,lennon1967}` where the citations are then sorted accordingly, but you will lose the possibility to specify a post/pre-note for each citation separately. For `\cites` commands though `sortcites` does nothing.

Comment: @Maïeul I'm compiling with ``latexmk``, and it does run ``biber``. I haven't changed my option at all - I set ``sorting = nyt, sortcites = true`` from the start.

Comment: @Sverre I assure that I obtain "Lennon" before "Mc Cartney". Which version of biber and biblatex do you use?

Comment: biber log should says what sorting it use. "INFO - Sorting list 'nyt' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'"

Comment: Mhhhh.... I get McCartney before Lennon in the citation as well. Just as one would expect knowing that `\cites` does not support `sortcites`.

Comment: @Maïeul Biber version 1.9, biblatex version 2.9a. I also get ``INFO - Sorting list 'nyt' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'``. But still McCartney before Lennon.

Comment: hum, strange, same version than my. Open .the bbl file and look at the order. I also suggest to delete .pdf, .bbl and .pdf file and try again. There is no rease to have this difference between you and me.

Comment: @Maïeul My ``.bbl`` does indeed put Lennon before McCartney. Does this mean that ``latexmk`` is not running ``biber`` enough times or something?

Comment: no, the .bbl is produce by biber. So I think it's latex which is not run enough. Try manually :)

Comment: The order in the `.bbl` file should be the same as the order in the bibliography. Since `\cites` cannot sort its arguments, though, that is irrelevant.

Comment: @Maïeul I always get McCartney before Lennon, also when running ``biber`` manually. Since ``moewe`` also gets that, it seems to be a mystery why you get something else. But as @mowew points out, I have indeed asked this question before (I couldn't find it by searching), so I'm voting to close my question as a duplicate.

Comment: also look at the .log file on LaTeX to be sur that the good .bbl file is loaded... and not any file in the tex path.

Comment: As a workaround, you may use `\cites{mccartney1965,lennon1967}`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit That won't work for reasons given in the comments to my duplicate question.

Comment: @Sverre Exact: if `prenote` or `postnote` is required, this workaround can't work... You may add this remark to your question.